# Elasticsearch cannot assign shard 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic Search and I'm having an index in red-state due to `can't assign shard 0` error.

I found a way to get the explanation but I'm still lost on understanding and fixing it.  The server's version is `7.5.2`.

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain'` returns

```
{
   "index":"event_tracking",
   "shard":0,
   "primary":false,
   "current_state":"unassigned",
   "unassigned_info":{
      "reason":"CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
      "at":"2020-12-22T14:51:08.943Z",
      "last_allocation_status":"no_attempt"
   },
   "can_allocate":"no",
   "allocate_explanation":"cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
   "node_allocation_decisions":[
      {
         "node_id":"cfsLU-nnRTGQG1loc4hdVA",
         "node_name":"xxx-clustername",
         "transport_address":"127.0.0.1:9300",
         "node_attributes":{
            "ml.machine_memory":"7992242176",
            "xpack.installed":"true",
            "ml.max_open_jobs":"20"
         },
         "node_decision":"no",
         "deciders":[
            {
               "decider":"replica_after_primary_active",
               "decision":"NO",
               "explanation":"primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
            },
            {
               "decider":"same_shard",
               "decision":"NO",
               "explanation":"the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists [[event_tracking][0], node[cfsLU-nnRTGQG1loc4hdVA], [P], recovery_source[existing store recovery; bootstrap_history_uuid=false], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=TObxz0EFQbylZsyTiIH7SA], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2020-12-22T14:51:08.943Z], delayed=false, allocation_status[fetching_shard_data]]]"
            },
            {
               "decider":"throttling",
               "decision":"NO",
               "explanation":"primary shard for this replica is not yet active"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I, more or less, understand the error message but I can't find the proper way to fix it. This server is not running on Docker, it's directly installed in the Linux machine.
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/recovery/event_tracking?v'` result

```
index          shard time  type           stage    source_host source_node target_host target_node                 repository snapshot files files_recovered files_percent files_total bytes bytes_recovered bytes_percent bytes_total translog_ops translog_ops_recovered translog_ops_percent
event_tracking 0     54.5m existing_store translog n/a         n/a         127.0.0.1   xxx-cluster                 n/a        n/a      0     0               100.0%        106         0     0               100.0%        2857898852  7061000      6489585                91.9%
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: `primary shard for this replica is not yet active` seems to imply that the primary shard is still recovering... Can you show what you get from `GET _cat/recovery/event_tracking?v` ?

Comment: If the primary have all recovered, you can try running `POST /_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true` in order to trigger the allocation of the unallocated shards

Comment: @Val I'll try both. The server is taking ages to return a response. Does the post has a body or it's empty?

Comment: None has a body. If the cluster takes ages to respond it's probably overloaded and also the reason why primary shards take time to recover

Comment: @Val I added the return of the recovery status. Does that give you any useful info?

Comment: Yes, the shard is still recovering, see last column `translog 91.9%`... When you see 100% there, you can try running `POST /_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true`